# What is "Parent" in Zoomable Circle Packing diagram d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, textbox

I want to create an svg in which labels only appear when it is zoomed. For this reason I am following [this example from mbostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535). I do not understand what is parent is these functions:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: d.parent refers to the parent node. Children would be referring to any children it has. By checking if it has a parent, then checking that it has no children, you can determine that a node is a leaf.

Comment: @RobFoley thanks! also what is root in the code?

Comment: See the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#nodes) for an explanation. It's the pack layout which puts these attributes on the nodes.

Comment: @altocumulus: Thanks again, the diagram to which am trying to add  this functionality (labels only appear when zoomed) is not a pack layout so how will I determine which element can replace root? for example in this fiddle I get an error root is not defined https://jsfiddle.net/n5v84svm/41/